# Python download zip bad request (right click save as)

Tags: python, selenium, request

I'm not sure if the title is correct and I tried to look for solutions to my problem without any success.

I'm able to download a zip file simply with

```
    import requests,os
    url="http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.23/chromedriver_linux64.zip"
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/6.0'}
    r=requests.get(url,headers)
    with open(os.path.basename(url), "wb") as archive:
        archive.write(r.content)
```

but when I try with the following `url='http://www.truefx.com/dev/data/2016/JANUARY-2016/EURUSD-2016-01.zip'` the requests return `<Response [400]>`. I can't download the above link neither with wget on linux shell and I observed that from the [website](https://pepperstone.com/en/client-resources/historical-tick-data) which contains the zip the only way to download it's right-click and save as. So I guess I should mimic something like that in python. I even tried selenium but again I wasn't able to download it.

Comment: Seems to be their problem, I'm not able to download the file, neither using the direct-link nor with the link on their website.

Comment: This is weird. Few hours ago I was able to download using save link as but now the server is broken.